# Search for a value in php with preg_match_all

Tags: php, pcre, preg-match-all

I've a string:

```
<li><a href="http://www.site.tv/watch/some-text-english-subbed-dubbed-online/" title="title">title</a></li><div class="clear"></div></ul><h3><a name="dot">.dot</a></h3><ul><li><a href="http://www.site.tv/watch/searched-too-some-words-english-subbed-dubbed-online/" title="title2">title22</a></li>
```

and I want to find "some-text" and "searched-too-some-words" with preg_match_all. 
But it don't work with this

```
preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/www\.site\.tv\/watch\/([^-]*)-english[^\/]*/s', $var, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

$result will be nothing

or

```
preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/www\.site\.tv\/watch\/(.*)-english[^\/]*/s', $var, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$result will be: http://www.site.tv/watch/some-text-english-subbed-dubbed-online/" title="title">title</a></li><div class="clear"></div></ul><h3><a name="dot">.dot</a></h3><ul><li><a href="http://www.site.tv/watch/searched-too-some-words-english-subbed-dubbed-online
```

is there a way to find the word after "http://www.site.tv/watch/" and until "-english"

regards
christian

Comment: Use something else as a delimiter and save yourself the inconvenience of having to escape all those forward slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are going to match a url with text before the word `english`.

Try

```
preg_match_all('/http\:\/\/www\.site\.tv\/watch\/(.*?)-english[^\/]*/s', $var, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

In fact, you don't need to escape the colon `:`. Better, you could use something else for delimiters, as Asad's comment said

```
preg_match_all('|http://www\.site\.tv/watch/(.*?)-english[^/]*|s', $var, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

That `.*?` thing is a lazy match - making the `.` to match as least character as possible until finding the next match/token, which in your case is `-english`